# Arithmetic operation gives incorrect result

Tags: c++, c, eclipse-cdt

I might be missing something very basic here. But I don't know how to figure out that basic thing. When I set T to 10 and dt to 0.1, I should get the result 101 but I am getting the result as 100. Why is it so?

```
n_sim_steps = (int)(T/dt) + 1
```

Furthermore, if I execute this as a watch in eclipse, it returns 101, but in code it results in 100.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
n_sim_steps = (int)(T/dt + 0.5) + 1
```

You are a victim of [precission loss](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/613738-division-precision-issue)

`10 / 0.1` may be `99.999999999999` because of this loss and may be casted back to `int` as `99`. Adding `0.5` and then casting would make sure that the result is rounded.

Comment: Isn't it better to add 1 if this is the case? If my result came out to be 99.499999999 than even adding 0.5 would be a problem.

Comment: @Shaun No, it is still better to add `0.5` for rounding because the error is going to be small. What if the result instead is 100.00001, adding 1 would be bad. `99.499999999` would be rounded to to `99` which is correct. Also adding `0.5` would work only for positive numbers. Subtract `-0.5` for negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You better to use ceil function.

function signature

```
double ceil (double x);
```

like ceil(2.3) will results  3